# gradle build "ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, gradle, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to build and run a Jetty embedded "hello world" application.

The build succeeds with no error, but when I try to run it I get an error. I assume this is because the jetty jar(s) are not added to the classpath when I run it. But I have not figured out the correct approach to remedying this in my gradle build.

My build.gradle is as follows....

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:+'
    implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:+'
    // implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:+'
    // implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:+'
    // implementation 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:+'
}
```

My application has two main executable classes. ChessServer and ChessClient.

The command I am using to run the ChessServer is as follows...

```
java -ea -cp build/classes/java/main/ ChessServer
```

And the specific error I am getting at runtime...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Server
    at ChessServer.main(ChessServer.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are building with gradle, you are probably best to run with gradle too rather than manually running via "java" at command line.

If you want to run your class, you'll need to specify the entire classpath (including your dependency jars). You've only told java where your classes are.

I suggest using a `JavaExec` task in Gradle.

Eg:

```
task run(type: JavaExec) {
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath 
   main = 'ChessServer'
}
```

Then from command line

```
gradle run
```

There's also the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) which can bundle your classes and dependencies as a zip.

Comment: Why does this run task still say "<=========----> 75% EXECUTING ", when my main method has already exited....?

Comment: No idea what your application is doing but the process is still running after you think it's finished. Perhaps you didn't shutdown jetty container or something? Not sure what operating system you're using but you should be able to see the process running via "ps" in Unix or task manager on Windoze

Comment: Correct. The jetty code was spawning another thread that I did not terminate.